# How to Reduce Execution Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

It's just my startup in SQL, I have 4.5 GB database from that I am trying to select records from specific dates and its 25 seconds execute. Is there a way to make it faster?

My query:

```
select a.*,b.ModelName
from Validation a
left Join ModelMaster b
    on SUBSTRING(a.STB,11,2) = b.ProductCode and
    Convert(int,substring(a.STB,9,2)) = b.BrandCode
Where STB in (Select STB From Scan_Data_For_Century) and
    a.date between '2015-01-14' and '2015-01-14'
```

Comment: How much time is the query taking to execute and how large are the tables?

Comment: Inline sql or stored procedure?

Comment: what are the index you have on the table ?

Comment: If this is a serious attempt at improving a large database you should remodel Validation table so you don't need to substring in the join.

Comment: check this will help you: http://www.infoworld.com/article/2628420/database/database-7-performance-tips-for-faster-sql-queries.html

Comment: What are the indexes in the tables? What does the query plan & statistics io output look like?

Comment: Thank you for your response
- Its takes 25 seconds to executes, problem is that there are total 5 queries similar.
- I am using non clustered index for all

Comment: `a.date between '2015-01-14' and '2015-01-14'` ???

Comment: @Suriiii. What exactly are the indexes? Without query plan + number of rows in the table everything is just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try query like this:

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.ModelName
FROM Scan_Data_For_Century sd
INNER JOIN Validation a
    ON a.STB = sd.STB AND a.date between '2015-01-14' and '2015-01-14'
LEFT JOIN ModelMaster b
    ON SUBSTRING(a.STB,11,2) = b.ProductCode AND Convert(int,substring(a.STB,9,2)) = b.BrandCode
```

I know, that must be a comment. Please, try query. If it wont help I will remove my answer.

Comment: Not faster? :) If `Scan_Data_For_Century.STB` column has index on it you can try change last string like `ON SUBSTRING(sd.STB,11,2) = b.ProductCode AND Convert(int,substring(sd.STB,9,2)) = b.BrandCode`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with cte as (
select 
    *, 
    ProductCode = SUBSTRING( STB, 11, 2 ), 
    BrandCode = Convert( int, substring( STB, 9, 2 ) ) 
from Validation
)
select
    a.*,
    c.ModelName
from 
    cte a
    inner join Scan_Data_For_Century b on ( b.STB = a.STB )
    left Join ModelMaster c on ( c.ProductCode = b.ProductCode ) and ( c.BrandCode = b.BrandCode )
Where     
    ( a.date = '2015-01-14' )
```

Also indexes on:

- Validation.STB
- Validation.Date
- Scan_Data_For_Century.STB
- ModelMaster.ProductCode
- ModelMaster.BrandCode

might be helpfull

Comment: I'm glad. How much faster?